# Understanding smart pointers but error: pointer being freed was not allocated

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, memory-leaks, smart-pointers

I am trying to understand smart pointers and have the following code:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 #include <memory>
 using namespace std;

 struct B 
 {
     string hello() { return "hello world"; }
 };

 class A
 {
 private:
     B* a;
 public:
     A() { a = new B; }
     ~A() { delete a; a = nullptr; }
     B* get() { return a; }
 };

 int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
     A a;
     shared_ptr<B> p(a.get());
     cout << p->hello() << endl;
     p.reset();
     return 0;
 }
```

What I am trying to do here, is access the raw pointer, but through the smart pointer.  It prints "hello world" just fine, and there are no errors when I comment out the destructor for A. However, when I uncomment it, I get the following error:

```
 test(9758,0x7fff738d9300) malloc: *** error for object 0x1001053a0: pointer 
 being freed was not allocated
 *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

What is going on here? Is the shared_ptr, p, calling the destructor when it goes out of scope or resets (to nullptr)? How is p dealing with the memory leak from not deleting A::a?

I understand that smart pointers generally handle new objects and this is probably a case not used often, but I want to try to learn this.

Answer (score 2):

> Is the shared_ptr, p, calling the destructor when it goes out of scope or resets (to nullptr)?

Yes, exactly.

> How is p dealing with the memory leak from not deleting A::a?

`p` thinks it owns the object, so it deletes it. There is no leak. But `a` also thinks it owns the object too, so it tries to delete it a second time and crashes.

> I understand that smart pointers generally handle new objects and this is probably a case not used often, but I want to try to learn this.

This is a case not used at all, because you can't have multiple objects owning the same memory at the same time, for exactly this reason.

The correct solution is to either make `class A` use `shared_ptr` internally:

```
class A {
    private:
        shared_ptr<B> b;
    public:
        A() { b.reset(new B); }
        shared_ptr<B> get() { return b; }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    A a;
    shared_ptr<B> p = a.get();
    cout << p->hello() << endl;
    p.reset();
    return 0;
}
```

Or simply don't take ownership of a raw pointer you didn't direct allocate yourself to begin with:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    A a;
    B *p = a.get();
    cout << p->hello() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The whole point of using smart pointers is to be *explicit* about who owns what, and how ownership is transferred around. Your example is violating that.

Answer (score 1):

`A a;` and `shared_ptr<B> p(a.get());` are pointing at the same allocated `B` object in memory. `p.reset()` destroys that `B` object, and then the `~A()` destructor tries to free it again.

From [`shared_ptr::reset()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/reset):

> If `*this` already owns an object and it is the last `shared_ptr` owning it, **the object is destroyed** through the owned `deleter`.

Answer (score 0):

Your p.reset() deletes the B object as it doesn't know anything about variable a owning it and you didn't increase p's reference count manually (which is not possible with shared_ptr as it is designed to only share a pointer by copying the shared_ptr object).

What you tried to do here with reset(ptr) is undefined behavior:

> If the object pointed to by ptr is already owned, the function results
>   in undefined behavior.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/reset

Comment: How can I manually increase/decrease the ref count? The formatting for cppreference is not conducive to learning imo. I have noticed that using unique_ptr doesn't give me these errors.

Comment: @HectorJ the only way to increment the refcount is to assign the `shared_ptr` to another `shared_ptr`. And yes, you can run into this same error when using `unique_ptr` in a similarly wrong manner